# Is there a setting to set too many requests?

Tags: php, apache

I am programming in PHP and I am wondering if there is a way to set up too many requests or does this need to be coded up manually? For example, if someone has opened 30 pages in 60 seconds, that is too many requests (and they may potentially be a bot), thus they get sent a too many requests HTTP status code.

If it is supposed to be done manually, what is the best practice to set up something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [ratelimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) by Apache.

Here is a sample provided by Apache. The rate limit is 400kb/second for the particular IP.

```
<Location "/downloads">
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 400 
</Location>
```

More specifically, you can try a module like [Mod Evasive](https://github.com/jzdziarski/mod_evasive) to prevent multiple requests from accessing the server. You can use a product like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-au/ddos/) to mitigate DDOS attacks.

If you really want to use PHP for this you can log the amount of requests from a given IP, and if requests from that IP is greater than a certain value, you can block the IP from accessing your page.

To do this, you can store the IP addresses in a database along with a date column indicating when they accessed your page, and calculate aggregates of their access in a particular period using SQL.

Comment: For rate limit, how do u actually set the limit?

Comment: Updated @James :) I think Mod Evasive would be a better fit for you. Check the hyperlink though to see if you understand how to implement it.

Comment: If you are getting a true DOS/DDOS attack and want protection against that, I don't think apache is typically the layer where you'd want to solve that

Comment: Very true, something like CloudFlare would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone that might not be using apache here is the nginx documenation
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/